# Arduino Mega ADK + Galaxy S3 + USB

Tags: galaxy, adk

i wanna buy a samsung galaxy s3, but i dont know if it can be connected. Does anybody knows it works? Do i need an otg usb cable to conect or it can be with normal usb cable?

Answer (score 1):

i have tested two android devices with ardunio mega ADK, Google Nexus one , and Samsung galaxy S3 .

Google Nexus one Works fine , but Samsung S3 doesn't responds to the board , to let it works you should use external power source (e.g 9V battery) , and its works fine , also you don't want to buy an otg usb cable , its works with the normal usb cable that comes with the phone .

Answer (score 1):

I tried to connect ardunio mega ADK successed before I upgrate the Android system. However, I can connect success rate about 20%. That's means  I only connect success twice every ten times.
But I can't connect success after the system upgrate to 4.1.2.